# is it possible to control external devices with ionic

Tags: ionic-framework

i want to learn a programming language for mobile 
one of my friends made an app to control drones with JAVA a (native one)
so i want to know if ionic or any cross platform else could do something like that

Comment: the question in another way

Comment: is it possible to program for imbedded systems with a cross platform language